# Debug USB Mouse/Keyboard on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, mouse

I have a recent computer, and wanted to boot into an older HD to retrieve some EFS files.  It works well, except I think it used to use a PS2 mouse/keyboard, and while in BIOS/pre-boot the lights for the mouse/keyboard is on, and they are working, but when it gets to the Windows XP bootup it does not find the USB KB/Mouse.  The lights are off.

There are no PS2 ports on this computer.. what should i do?

Comment: could you please describe your problem a little more? Does the usb-maouse and keyboard work when it is fully booted? What service-pack do you have installed? Can you open the Device-Manager and look for any problems?

Comment: I'm stuck at the user log in screen, without a kb or mouse, I cannot login.

Comment: It's an old version of Windows, probably never had a USB kb/mouse plugged into it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the BIOS has a [Legacy USB Support](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/usbcompat.mspx) setting you may want to enable it.  This will trick the OS in thinking the USB keyboard and mouse are PS2.

Comment: Looks like the BIOS doesn't have it, went through everything.  Thanks.

Comment: If the computer is on the network, you could try RDPing into it (assuming you have the admin password).  If Remote Desktop isn't enabled, you can enable it by editing the registry remotely.

Comment: Actually, you may be able to copy the files off the drive as a network share.  If no share was setup, you could also try using \\ipaddress\c$ to get in the root of C.  You may need to connect with the username/password, but that should allow you access to the EFS certificates.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - I'm relatively sure RDP is not enabled though.  I'll try to look into this thanks.

Comment: Doesn't appear the computer is connected to the network - the Windows is very old so it's possible it's not..

Comment: If I use a Windows disk to "repair" the Windows (maybe updating some of it) do you think it'll mess up with the EFS?

Comment: First, I would attempt to boot to Last Known Good Configuration (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307852).  Each time someone logs into Windows, this is updated.  If you are unable to login, Windows will see what changed (maybe a bad driver, or disk corruption) and use a backup copy of the files.  Hopefully that will clear up the keyboard/mouse issue.

Comment: I'm still unsure about the "repair" because I don't remember if that will blow away the users.  At this point I would be considering imaging the drive, just in case.  I thought there was a way to use the recovery console for EFS, but I'm still looking that up.